# Oracle - looping though a list of date ranges with CONNECT BY LEVEL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to expand upon another article to reach my needs. I am trying to build out a calendar based on our fiscal periods and seem to be creating an infinite loop, or rather one soo large SQL is squashing the query. A procedural solution will not work in the environment that I am trying to build this into, I am only able to use built-in features of the software otherwise I am in breach of my support agreement.

I will break down some of the output so you can see the raw data.

```
select distinct ap.accounting_year, ap.accounting_period, ap.date_from, ap.date_until
    from accounting_period ap
    where ap.accounting_period not in (0,13) and ap.accounting_year = :FY 
    order by ap.accounting_year, ap.accounting_period
```

This will output the following

```
2018    1   01-OCT-17   28-OCT-17
2018    2   29-OCT-17   25-NOV-17
2018    3   26-NOV-17   30-DEC-17
2018    4   31-DEC-17   27-JAN-18
2018    5   28-JAN-18   24-FEB-18
2018    6   25-FEB-18   31-MAR-18
2018    7   01-APR-18   28-APR-18
2018    8   29-APR-18   26-MAY-18
2018    9   27-MAY-18   30-JUN-18
2018    10  01-JUL-18   28-JUL-18
2018    11  29-JUL-18   25-AUG-18
2018    12  26-AUG-18   29-SEP-18
```

Now when I run the following query which I added an additional prompt for the period to limit the above result to 1-row and things work as intended.

```
WITH 
fiscal as (
    select distinct ap.accounting_year, ap.accounting_period, ap.date_from, ap.date_until
    from accounting_period ap
    where ap.accounting_period not in (0,13) and ap.accounting_year = :FY and ap.accounting_period = :FP 
    order by ap.accounting_year, ap.accounting_period       
),
calendar AS (
     SELECT f.accounting_year, f.accounting_period, f.date_from + ROWNUM -1 fiscal_day
       FROM dual, fiscal f
     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= f.date_until - f.date_from + 1
)
select * from  calendar;
```

Output;

```
2018    9   27-MAY-18
2018    9   28-MAY-18
2018    9   29-MAY-18
2018    9   30-MAY-18
2018    9   31-MAY-18
2018    9   01-JUN-18
2018    9   02-JUN-18
2018    9   03-JUN-18
2018    9   04-JUN-18
2018    9   05-JUN-18
2018    9   06-JUN-18
2018    9   07-JUN-18
2018    9   08-JUN-18
2018    9   09-JUN-18
2018    9   10-JUN-18
2018    9   11-JUN-18
2018    9   12-JUN-18
2018    9   13-JUN-18
2018    9   14-JUN-18
2018    9   15-JUN-18
2018    9   16-JUN-18
2018    9   17-JUN-18
2018    9   18-JUN-18
2018    9   19-JUN-18
2018    9   20-JUN-18
2018    9   21-JUN-18
2018    9   22-JUN-18
2018    9   23-JUN-18
2018    9   24-JUN-18
2018    9   25-JUN-18
2018    9   26-JUN-18
2018    9   27-JUN-18
2018    9   28-JUN-18
2018    9   29-JUN-18
2018    9   30-JUN-18
```

In the end, I would like to be able to run this to output the records for all 12 periods and create a fiscal year calendar since this view does not exist in the current database.

I can post my entire query if requested, but this is where I am stuck, I was able to build the rest of my script by adding prompts to select the fiscal year and period in the WITH clause, but when I implement this into the end report I will have to create a view where the prompt will not be available within the WITH.

Thank You

Comment: Can you try replacing ROWNUM  with level ...

Comment: the first 28 records work as expected then it starts jumping around, I was able to see over 2200 records, which is more than the 364 for a fiscal year

Comment: Can you post the input data set and what output you expect to see ?

Comment: Why is this tagged with tsql? Mistake?

Comment: my input dataset would be my second code snip with the 2018 records, my expected output would be a row for every day between Oct 1, 2017, and Sep 29, 2018, in the same format as my sample output, just more records. I can post it but it will add 364 lines to my post.

Comment: @stickybit I was trying to specify that I am unable to use a declare, begin and end in this query so I added tsql.. No custom PL/SQL functions, I am not sure why now that I think about.

Comment: @CodyWhite: Then you should probably remove plsql too. ;) And state in the question, that a procedural solution is no option for you. And add the oracle tag instead (this is for Oracle isn't it? `ROWNUM`, `DUAL`, `CONNECT BY` ... at least it looks very Oracle'ish to me...)

Comment: @stickybit you are right it is Oracle. Thanks, I'll make the updates! I was not sure the best way to phrase it using proper nomenclature.

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your question. Is that part of a procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well your need, this could be what you need:

```
select accounting_year, accounting_period, date_from, date_until, date_from + level -1 as calendare_date
from yourResult
   connect by date_from + level -1 <= date_until
     and prior accounting_year = accounting_year
     and prior accounting_period = accounting_period
     and prior sys_guid() is not null
order by accounting_year, accounting_period
```

For example, with a reduced set of data:

```
with yourResult(accounting_year, accounting_period, date_from, date_until) as (
    select    2018, 1 , to_date('01-OCT-17', 'dd-mon-yy'), to_date('05-OCT-17', 'dd-mon-yy') from dual union all
    select    2018, 2 , to_date('06-OCT-17', 'dd-mon-yy'), to_date('07-OCT-17', 'dd-mon-yy') from dual union all
    select    2018, 3 , to_date('08-OCT-17', 'dd-mon-yy'), to_date('10-oct-17', 'dd-mon-yy') from dual
)
select accounting_year, accounting_period, date_from, date_until,
       date_from + level -1 as calendare_date
from yourResult
   connect by date_from + level -1 <= date_until
     and prior accounting_year = accounting_year
     and prior accounting_period = accounting_period
     and prior sys_guid() is not null
order by accounting_year, accounting_period;
```

you have:

```
ACCOUNTING_YEAR ACCOUNTING_PERIOD DATE_FROM DATE_UNTI CALENDARE
--------------- ----------------- --------- --------- ---------
           2018                 1 01-OCT-17 05-OCT-17 01-OCT-17
           2018                 1 01-OCT-17 05-OCT-17 02-OCT-17
           2018                 1 01-OCT-17 05-OCT-17 03-OCT-17
           2018                 1 01-OCT-17 05-OCT-17 04-OCT-17
           2018                 1 01-OCT-17 05-OCT-17 05-OCT-17
           2018                 2 06-OCT-17 07-OCT-17 06-OCT-17
           2018                 2 06-OCT-17 07-OCT-17 07-OCT-17
           2018                 3 08-OCT-17 10-OCT-17 08-OCT-17
           2018                 3 08-OCT-17 10-OCT-17 09-OCT-17
           2018                 3 08-OCT-17 10-OCT-17 10-OCT-17
```

Comment: Perfect!, I had to tweak this a bit since I had to add one more level to my WITH statement, but it was an easy modification. Thank you very much.